# is this question off-topic? (How old are japaneses when they finish learning kanjis in school?)

Tags: discussion

I wanted to ask this question in the board, though I'm not sure if it's off-topic or not.

How old are japaneses when they finish learning kanjis in school?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a compulsory education, it takes 6 + 3 = 9 years, just about 15 years old.

After that depends on the person who takes another schools high school for 3 years, prep school for the university 2-3 years, college 2-4 years and the university for 4 to 16 years. But I am sure after learning the dictionary 漢和辞典 usage, we were/'ve been not taught Kanji's, **except** the word is new or needs a help for understanding.

Comment: 6 + 3 = 12 ? what did you mean ? It takes 12 or 9 for compulsory education? I dont know if you start compulsory education at 6 or 3

Comment: I'm very bad at math. I just thought about high school takes another 3 years., but it's not  a compulsory education.

Comment: so you end compulsory education at the age of 15, but after that you can take even 3+4+16 , 23 years more of education? really?

Comment: 6+3+(3+4) high-uni course, this is popular. between high and uni many people had been in prep school which is a school for passing university entrance exam. But now students are less than the supply, everybody can go almost any uni. In the uni, allowed to stay 8 years in bachelor, 4 years in Master and Doctor could be lifetime. Myself, after fed up with the low quality education in high school, I decided learn from real or a city library.

Comment: I dont know if university studies make sense anymore . Perhaps for those jobs you need the title. For example, you complete 5 years of computer engineering and you end being an expensive to hire useless professional who doesnt know 33% or 25% of what's needed to know to make your job. In 2000 or so the director of Google said it takes 10 years to learn programming. Nowadays I think it's 15 or more , but you can't be until your 33's or 35's to start working

Comment: I'm old, when I wanted to learn computer thingy, no teachers were available in my town, no English teachers speak fluent. I worked in a cafe then a watch maker and Dutch film companies. I am retired and a freeman.